# ElasticSearch ignoring sort when filtered

Tags: elasticsearch

ElasticSearch Version: 0.90.1, JVM: 1.6.0_51(20.51-b01-457)

I'm trying to do two things with my ElasticSearch query:  1) filter the results based on a boolean (searchable) and "open_date < tomorrow" and 2) two sort by the field "open_date" DESC

This produces the following query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "prefix": {
            "name": "foobar"
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "foobar"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "name": {
              "query": "foobar"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_number_should_match": 1
    },
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "and": [
          {
            "term": {
              "searchable": true
            }
          },
          {
            "range": {
              "open_date": {
                "lt": "2013-07-16"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "open_date": "desc"
    }
  ]
}
```

However, the results that come back are not being sorted by "open_date".  If I remove the filter:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "prefix": {
            "name": "foobar"
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "foobar"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "name": {
              "query": "foobar"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_number_should_match": 1
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "open_date": "desc"
    }
  ]
}
```

... the results come back as expected.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about the Tire code, but the JSON does not correctly construct a filtered query. My guess is that this overflows and causes the sort element to also not be correctly parsed.

A filtered query should be constructed like this (see http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/filtered-query/ ):

```
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": { // Note: this contains both query and filter
         "query": {
            "bool": {
               "should": [
                  {
                     "prefix": {
                        "name": "foobar"
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "query_string": {
                        "query": "foobar"
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "match": {
                        "name": {
                           "query": "foobar"
                        }
                     }
                  }
               ],
               "minimum_number_should_match": 1
            }
         },
         "filter": {
            "and": [
               {
                  "term": {
                     "searchable": true
                  }
               },
               {
                  "range": {
                     "open_date": {
                        "lt": "2013-07-16"
                     }
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   },
   "sort": [
      {
         "open_date": "desc"
      }
   ]
}
```

Cheers,
Boaz